# What occupation should be used for non metallic energetic materials in Quantum espresso?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, quantum-chemistry, quantum-mechanics

I am trying to understand the Quantum espresso input file and I intend to do DFT calculation on an Energetic material (TKX-50) consisting of C, H, O, AND N. I have seen that "smearing" should be set as occupation for metals, but what "Occupation" should be used for my material.

Answer (score 3):

Usually for materials with a band gap you can just not specify any option for `occupations` and the calculation runs perfectly fine.
I'm not familiar with TKX-50, but if it is an insulator (with a wide band-gap) and you really want to specify `occupations` you can use the `fixed` keyword.